# Is there a way to make an animation that rotates an image or video along the x and y axis using python moviepy?

Tags: python, animation, moviepy

I'm typing a script that automates video editing using the Moviepy library in python.

So far everything works fine, but I just need to implement one simple thing: animate rotating an image on its x and y axis.

This is something I want to achieve:

[image: x and y axis rotation]

I read the Moviepy documents and I can't find anything about rotating on  x or y axis.

If Moviepy indeed does not support that, can you suggest some codes or libraries for me that goes well with Moviepy?

I Googled a bit before asking, but the only useful result I got is this post
[Rotate an image around its x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186787/rotate-an-image-around-its-x-axis) that was answered way back in 2016. I'm worried that since so much time has passed the code might not be relevant anymore, or maybe there is a better and faster way to do it now?

Edit I tried the code from said post from 2016. I copied and paste it, changed the image path to where the image is, double checked the path to make sure it's correct, installed POV-Ray, installed Editor DLL's, and it gives me this error:

```
Image output to STDOUT/STDERR not supported on this platform
Failed to start render: Cannot open file.
```

[image]

I'm at lost. Google doesn't even have any result about this error.